# What change of variables would make this parallelogram into a rectangle?

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

What should I make x and y equal to get a nice rectangle for the region? :) Atleast how do I approach it? Thank you

[image]

Comment: the intersection of both restrictions

Comment: You mean find the intersection coordinate of the lines and make that equal to u and v?

Comment: at $(-3,0)$ you could rotate the lines but for different angles each, 'cuz the lines are not at 90 degrees

Comment: You can get an rectangle easily by making it "$|x| \le 1, |y|\le 20562$". Not very useful? Yes, but you didn't give any conditions. All you say is that you want to change $x, y$ to make it a rectangle. If you want a useful answer, you have to tell us the full problem - or at least enough so that we know what should be preserved, and what may be changed.

Answer (score 0):

You're rectangular region would have bounds kinda like $-a \leq u \leq a$ and $-b \leq v \leq b$ right? Well you already have $|x + 2y| \leq 3$ so putting $3u = x+2y$ makes it so that $|u| \leq 1$ and the other equation is $|x - y| \leq3$ so putting $3v = x-y$ gives you $|v| \leq 1$. Solving these simultaneously for $x$ and $y$ give you:
$$x = u + 2 v, \; y = u - v$$

Conveniently, this approach also makes the limits for $u$ and $v$ really self evident